# Querulous on scala 2.9

Tags: scala, querulous

Has anyone had success with querulous on scala 2.9? 
The jar from twitter seems to rely on 2.7

Comment: Bueller?... Bueller?... Bueller?

Answer (score -1):

there are releases for 2.8 at http://maven.twttr.com/com/twitter/querulous/2.6.5/

you can ask when to expect 2.9 release here https://github.com/twitter/querulous

afaik all of its dependencies now have versions for 2.9, so it's just a matter of time to release querulous as well