# Having SBT 0.11 pulling in querulous from github by using information in build.sbt

Tags: scala, github, sbt

I would like to just add some information to build.sbt and have it pull in 
https://github.com/twitter/querulous

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following lines:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" %% "querulous-core" % "2.7.0"

resolvers += "Twitter repo" at "http://maven.twttr.com"
```

Note also, that querulous is kinda [abandoned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9133614/298389), so you may want to switch to [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2318935/298389).

### EDIT

If you looking for ways to fetch querulous directly from github, AFAIK there is no one via `build.sbt` but you can configure you can do this via `project/MyBuild.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project(".", file("Foo"),
  settings = Defaults.defaultSettings
) dependsOn(querulous)

  lazy val querulous = uri("git://github.com/twitter/querulous")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look for a replacement, I was basically curious how to pull from github.

Comment: Changed the path of the uri to http://github.com/nkallen/querulous but that was it.  Thank you. Now to find a better library.